# Get the SQL for a Doctrine 2 entity insert

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is it possible to get the SQL for a Doctrine 2 entity insert?

For example, let's say I have this:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setName('bar');
$em->persist($foo);
$em->flush();
```

Is there a way to get the SQL for the INSERT statement there? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could activate the query log in your MySQL server (guessing it's it) :
in /etc/mysql/my.ini (usual place) :

```
[mysqld]
log=/tmp/mysql.log
```

then read this file where you will find each issued query.

Comment: And for the uninitiated, you might need to run `sudo service mysql restart` after you update the config file.

Comment: this is not always convenient when your Database is data-intensive.  It will be good to have a way to do some logging programmatically

Comment: Horrible idea, MariaDB (MySQL) would not restart; if you do this. Btw: In mariadb 10.3.22-MariaDB-1ubuntu1 . I guess it already had log_error variable in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

Answer (score 9):

You could try the SQL-Logger:

```
$em->flush(); // to write cached stuff down and isolate the following

// activate logger
$em->getConnection()
    ->getConfiguration()
    ->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setName('bar');
$em->persist($foo);
$em->flush();

// disable logger
$em->getConnection()
    ->getConfiguration()
    ->setSQLLogger(null);
```

It works with other DBMS than MySQL too. There are also other possibilities to write in files. Look here:

https://www.brunsware.de/blog/symfony/monolog-doctrine-logfile.html

http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/logging-doctrine-queries-in-symfony2/